# Stripe one time payment checkout node

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup a donation system where the `unit_price` must come from the customer on the front-end side.

This code is working fine for me (see code below), but when I remove the 2000 and replace it with `req.body.amount` coming from the front-end I get this error:

> Prices require an 'unit_amount' or 'unit_amount_decimal' parameter to be set.

I tried `parseInt(req.body.amount, 10)` or `parseFloat(req.body.amount)` but I got a NaN error. How can I do this correctly?

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: 'Donation',
          },
          unit_amount: 2000,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
    cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  });

  res.json({ id: session.id });
});
```

Comment: What does `req.body.amount`, or even `req.body` actually contain?  It sounds like it's not coming through properly.

Comment: I const amount = await req.body.amount and now it's working but I'm getting another error although everything is working fine now. The error is: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client and it's coming from the frontend const response = await fetch('api/contribution/create-checkout-session', {
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({amount}),
    })

If I remove the header I get the same error from before.

Comment: That sounds like a node error, not a client side error - did you try googling the error?